# Undo bg; Undo putting a process into the background?

Tags: bash, process-management

I've started a long running and machine hog process. I've hit `CTRL-Z` to stop it. I've then put it in the background with `bg`. Oops, I should have restarted with `fg` so that I could easily stop and start it again. What is the easiest way to stop a process that was just put into the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted, `fg` = foreground.

You can also try `jobs` to see them. Then `%N` can be used with `fg` or `kill` e.g. `fg %4`

Answer (score 12):

Just run `fg` or `fg %+`.  The job processing will keep track of the job and you can just tell it to go into the foreground again.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to stop it to put it into the foreground, just `fg` it.